# Dojo multiple popup windows?

Tags: javascript, dojo

Can some one tell me how to open multiple popup windows without freezing the parent window. Actually what I want to do is this: I have implemented a Dojo grid. If some one clicks on a cell I want to open a popup window with information in the cell. I have already done that. But the problem I can't click on the grid again to open another popup until I close the popup I have already open. Also I prefer the popup has minimize capability. Any help? I am new to Dojo related development. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is sort of the nature of dialog windows. Just like with the native `alert()` you have to dismiss the first before the program will let you proceed with anything. Have you looked at dojox.layout.FloatingPane? It's somewhat buggy (very experimental), but it may be worth a look. Of course, you may be able to hack dijit.Dialog into doing what you want as well, but it's not its intended behaviour.

Comment: @Frode thanks for you comment. I will look in to that..